# Canvas game trying to add another object to collect for more points

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

Im creating a side project that involves a snake getting food and tallying up in the score. I am now trying to add a mouse object, a mouse variable and mouse function for bonus points that will only be appearing at random times and for a random amount of time.

As you can see in the JS Fiddle I have added it without errors but unfortunately now it just goes through the food rather than collects it and doesn't randomly pull in a mouse food object at random times.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 

<html lang="en">

<head>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/CPega/

Comment: I don't think you understand what is happening in the program

Comment: I do understand whats happening in the code and hows it running I'm just not able to add another food object named mouse and it currently clashes with the food

Comment: I know you can [take from a tutorial](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/html5-game-tutorial-make-a-snake-game-using-html5-canvas-jquery) and add a bit, but from what I can tell you don't know *why* it works, you are only messing with values hoping for the best. If you try to actually *understand* what's happening problems like this will solve them self (:

Comment: @ZachSaucier : you should be fully confident in what you say, and just draw the logical conclusions from that point. (my conclusion was a laughter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed you condition where you check the collision with the food for this and it seems to work:

```
if (nx == food.x && ny == food.y)
```

If you want to add the mouse, place the || operator like this:

```
if ((nx == food.x && ny == food.y) || (nx == mouse.x && ny == mouse.y))
```

At the moment, you were doing a && so it needed to equals the mouse AND the food.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CPeg2/2/)

Comment: Hi yes this works but it isn't adding another food object called mouse this is what I couldn't get working and it was doing the same for me only adding one food into the canvas,

Comment: You don't seem to draw the mouse, you only draw the food and obstacle, adding paint_cell(mouse.x, food.y); seems to add the mouse, but the collision isn't working, at least the food collision is working and the mouse is showing.

Comment: I have drew the mouse and the food throughout the jQuery although it is running the same formulas.